# Brazilian savings account, understanding "saldos por dia base"

Tags: savings-account, brazil

Translating "saldos por dia base" into English, we get "balance per day base".  Literal translation.  In my savings account, I see a calendar showing a month.  In some days, I see an amount.  That makes me think that I made an investment on the savings account on that day.  I suppose that if I put another amount on some of those days, the values will add up.  I suppose the bank keeps these values on days because it is always on those days that they pay me interest.  Is that correct?

**Question**.  So if I want to take that money off of the savings account and put into another investment, then I guess I should wait for each of those days (so I'm paid) and then make the reinvestment on that same day.  Does that make sense?  Am I reading this thing properly?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to know whether you are reading it correctly, you need to get the actual text to a native speaker who understands Brazilian banking practice. One phrase in isolation, on an English -based site, may not get reliable answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suppose the bank keeps these values on days because it is always on those days that they pay me interest. Is that correct?

Yes, that's correct. These base days are also known as deposit "anniversaries".

> So if I want to take that money off of the savings account and put into another investment, then I guess I should wait for each of those days (so I'm paid) and then make the reinvestment on that same day. Does that make sense? Am I reading this thing properly?

You are again correct. You won't be paid any interests if you withdraw before the anniversary (or the next business day) of that amount.

[Source](https://riconnect.rico.com.vc/blog/resgate-poupanca/) (in Portuguese)